# KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is missing)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, android-studio, android-sdk

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I recently installed Android Studio, but whenever I try to run a Hello World app, I get this error:

```
/home/praveen/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is missing).
```

Comment: maybe u have a 32 bit system ,, try upgrading it n then try ... android emulator also requires 4gb ram and higher .

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Either your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios.  Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.

Comment: I am having this error on a Mac.  Solution isn't applicable to Macs because they have no BIOS.  What to do then?

Comment: Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it - What is the process to do that ????

Comment: How to go into bios?

Comment: @Riddhi, it depends on your computer.  Usually hit DEL or F12 or F1 when it says.

Answer (score 81):

Use the below command to check whether the KVM is installed in the machine or not,

```
kvm-ok
```

Output:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Output like the below means,

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

In this scenario need to install KVM using the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: praveen@praveen-Lenovo-B590:~$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
praveen@praveen-Lenovo-B590:~$

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cpu-checker` for `kvm-ok`.

Comment: @vembutech after executing command `kvm-ok ` I got an output that- "does not exist". So, I've installed it using the above mentioned command.  It has been downloaded. Last line is `Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...` now I run the `kvm-ok ` command again. But again it says "does not exist"

Comment: libvirt-bin is no longer used: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089753/e-package-libvirt-bin-has-no-installation-candidate

Answer (score 18):

```
HP-EliteBook-820-G1:/opt/android-studio/bin$ sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Affter bios setting, I used the following command

```
sudo modprobe kvm_intel
```

Now is ok

Comment: this solution worked perfect for my Ubuntu 14.0

Comment: this fixed it for me on Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit

Answer (score 11):

Worked on Ubuntu 15.04, Intel's CPU

1. `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm`
2. Enable Virtualization Technology in BIOS
3. `sudo kvm-ok`

Answer (score 6):

I had tried the command,

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

but unfortunately it didn't work. Then I changed owner (`rohanverma` is user in my case) by using,

```
sudo chown rohanverma:rohanverma -R /dev/kvm
```

which worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.  First had to enable on BIOS and then use `chown` as there was `no permissions`

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same error. But I'm running Ubuntu on the VMware. Ubuntu is installed on the VMware. So the steps to resolve the problem is different from pure ubuntu machine. The complains went away with the following steps:

1. `sudo apt install cpu-checker`
2. In VMware, go setting->Processors->Virtualization Engine, check "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI.
3. `sudo kvm-ok`

Answer (score 1):

Close any other hypervisors before starting Android Studio. I received the same error message when I tried to run an Android Virtual Device and had a Virtual Box VM running at the same time.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/671553)

Comment: @earthmeLon I fixed it.