# KVM is required to run this AVD

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization, android-studio

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I am trying to set up Android Studio for the first time. When I run my simple "Hello World" app, it gives me a pop-up that says

> KVM is required to run this AVD.
>   Unknown Error
>
> Please file a bug against Android Studio

[image: popup]

But when I run simply `kvm-ok` it outputs:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Comment: Did you check this Ask Ubuntu [thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/564910/550550)?

Comment: Yes i have, but the thing is that my CPU does support virtualization and is enabled from BIOS!

Comment: You might try to just run 'kvm' as that will run a KVM with (x86) Bios with -enable-kvm being set. It will eventually stop as it has nothing to boot, but you will see if kvm can be used.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Starting with Ubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint Tara you need to install qemu-kvm

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Check the ownership of /dev/kvm

```
ls -al /dev/kvm
```

Check which users are in the kvm group

```
grep kvm /etc/group
```

Output from the above command

```
kvm:x:some_number:
```

If there is nothing rightwards of the final `:`, there are no users in the kvm group.

To add the current user to the kvm group

```
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

which adds the user to the group, and check once again with `grep kvm /etc/group`.

A restart may be required for the permissions to take effect.

Official answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300811/android-studio-dev-kvm-device-permission-denied)

Comment: after adduser run this too...`sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm`

Comment: Thanks @rogoro. Running `chown` solved problem without restart.

Comment: Installing `qemu-kvm` is really not necessary for Android Studio, one can simply create the `kvm` (system) group and install a udev permission override to enable user access. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61984745/624066

Comment: @vamsi That does not really make sense. Do one or the other. If you add $USER to the `kvm` group that should be enough. Of course you have to logout/login. You have group rights then. Running that `chown` command makes $USER the owner of that device. That is not recommended as this is a strong change in system defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Change sdk emulator folder permission. This is worked for me.

```
chmod 777 -R {sdk folder}/emulator
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635879/kvm-is-required-to-run-this-avd-unknown-error-please-file-a-bug-against-androi

Comment: It is actually a permission denied on KVM rather on android emulator.

Comment: Either your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios. Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.

Comment: Thanks! Changing permission to 777 for /emulator did the job

Answer (score 0):

To run KVM, you need a processor that supports hardware virtualization.

To see if your processor supports hardware virtualization, you can review the output from this command:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

- If 0 it means that your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization.
- If 1 or more it does - but you still need to make sure that    virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

**Installation of KVM**

Cosmic (18.10) or later

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

You need to ensure that your username is added to the group libvirtd, and kvm:

```
sudo adduser `id -un` libvirt
sudo adduser `id -un` kvm
```

**Verify Installation**

Run `kvm-ok` on the command line.

```
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Logout or restart for changes to take effect.

Sources:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-check
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Answer (score -1):

I usually run

```
sudo chown username -R /dev/kvm
```

but this is only good for a while. Looking for a better solution.

There is also another command:

```
sudo adduser username kvm
```

Answer (score -1):

Login as a root user `sudo su` goto the studio installation dir with`cd ${path_of _installation_dir}/android-studio/bin` and relaunch the sdk with `./studio.sh`. Then try relaunching your avd

Comment: *Never* log in as the root user! There's nothing you could do as root, that you can't do with `sudo`. And if you only need the permissions of a specific group, `sg` if you belong to it, `sudo -g` if you don't — `sg kvm <path-to-your-android-studio>/bin/studio.sh` in this case, given the `kvm` group has read+write permission on `/dev/kvm`.