# E: Package 'libvirt-bin' has no installation candidate

Tags: kvm-virtualization, 18.10

I'm trying to install KVM\qemu on Ubuntu 18.10.

According to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) I'm running the command:

```
apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

and get an error about the packge "libvirt-bin" and "ubuntu-vm-builder":

```
E: Package 'libvirt-bin' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-vm-builder
```

I see that the package "libvirt-bin" is [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libvirt-bin&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

The main repository is set.
Anything that I'm doing wrong?
Couldn't find any info regrading this issue.

Is it the new Ubuntu version (18.10)?

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are correct: The `libvirt-bin` package was dropped in 18.10.

Quoting from https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2016/11/msg00518.html

> The package was split into two parts:
>
> libvirt-daemon-system
>
> libvirt-clients
>
> In most cases you probably want both of them at the same time.

So instead of `libvirt-bin` use `libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients`:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

Comment: The clarification is because this was used as a dupe (so upvoted) and the other user didn't understand...

Comment: I've updated the ubuntu wiki

Comment: Works on 20.04 too :)

Comment: Nice Thanks Good comment

Comment: 22.04 still works