# configuraing VM acceleration Issue on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: android, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, 18.10

I just switched to Ubuntu and I'm following the instructions on
[Configuring VM acceleration on Linux](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?utm_source=android-studio#vm-linux)

I typed this command

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils ia32-libs-multiarch
```

and got the following error:

```
E: Package 'libvirt-bin' has no installation candidate  
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-vm-builder  
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch
```

I looked for the package [here on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=amd64&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=libvirt-bin), but it looks like it's not there for Cosmic distribution.

Is there is a way that I configure VM acceleration equivalent to that explained in the tutorial?

**Edit**: [KVM\qemu installation issue (18.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089753/kvm-qemu-installation-issue-18-10) has an answer explaining that the package `libvirt-bin` was split into`libvirt-daemon-system` and `libvirt-clients`, but I need a solution for the other packages `ubuntu-vm-builder` and `ia32-libs-multiarch` too.

Comment: @user535733 what about  **ubuntu-vm-builder** ?

Comment: No that's not what @user535733 meant with the duplicate.  Please read the duplicate again: `libvirt-bin` = `libvirt-daemon-system` + `libvirt-clients`

Comment: @Fabby then the duplicate does not fully answer my question, I still can't configure VM acceleration for android.

Comment: Are you sure you still need the 32 bit libraries `ia32-libs-multiarch`? These were for compatibility with 32 bit apps etc. so that they could run in a 64 bit system. If everything is now converted to 64 bit system you won't need them.

Comment: @user68186 can't find vmbuilder for Cosmic though
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=vm